# v8 custom map and reduce functions order of magnitude faster than the builtins

Tags: javascript, performance, v8

So here is my "benchmark":

```
function id (el) {return el;}

function fakeMap (arr, fn){
  var ret = new Array(arr.length);
  for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
    ret[i] = fn(arr[i], i, arr);
  }
  return ret;
}

function arrCopyFor(arr) {
  var ret = new Array(arr.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    ret[i] = arr[i];
  }
  return ret;
}

function arrCopyMap(arr) {
  return arr.map(id);
}

function arrCopyFakeMap (arr) {
  return fakeMap(arr, id);
}

var hugeArray = new Array(20000000);
function buildHugeArray() {
  for (var i = 0; i < hugeArray.length; i++) {
    hugeArray[i] = i;
  }
  print("HugeArr: " + hugeArray.length.toString());
}


function time(fn) {
  var before = Date.now(),
      ret = fn(hugeArray);
  var after = Date.now();
  return (after - before);
}

buildHugeArray();
print("Real map ms:", time(arrCopyMap));
print("Fake map ms:", time(arrCopyFakeMap));
print("For loop ms:", time(arrCopyFor));
```

The output I get:

```
d8 map.js
HugeArr: 20000000
Real map ms: 1541
Fake map ms: 110
For loop ms: 128
```

I would expect the builtin to be a little faster, but it turns out the custom map is more than 10x faster. I know this is not a very good way to benchmark functions but I don't expect the method accounts for this large differences.

Even more demonstrative were the corresponding results for reduce:

```
function sum (el1, el2) {return el1 + el2;}

function fakeReduce (arr, fn, initial) {
  if (typeof initial === 'undefined') {
    initial = fn[0];
  }
  for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
    initial = fn(initial, arr[i], i, arr);
  }
  return initial;
}

function arrSumFor(arr) {
  var ret = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    ret += arr[i];
  }
  return ret;
}

function arrSumReduce(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(sum);
}

function arrSumFakeReduce (arr) {
  return fakeReduce(arr, sum);
}

var hugeArray = new Array(20000000);
function buildHugeArray() {
  for (var i = 0; i < hugeArray.length; i++) {
    hugeArray[i] = i;
  }
  print("HugeArr: " + hugeArray.length.toString());
}


function time(fn) {
  var before = Date.now(),
      ret = fn(hugeArray);
  var after = Date.now();
  return (after - before);
}

buildHugeArray();
print("Real reduce ms:", time(arrSumReduce));
print("Fake reduce ms:", time(arrSumFakeReduce));
print("For loop ms:", time(arrSumFor));
```

The output:

```
$ d8 reduce.js
HugeArr: 20000000
Real reduce ms: 1339
Fake reduce ms: 84
For loop ms: 43
```

Also if I overwrite the Array's prototype putting

```
Array.prototype.reduce = function (fn, initial) {
  return fakeReduce (this, fn, initial);
};
```

at the top of the file I get:

```
$ d8 reduce.js
HugeArr: 20000000
Real reduce ms: 109
Fake reduce ms: 84
For loop ms: 39
```

Is this a v8 (or possibly crankshaft?) bug or am I counting something wrong?

Comment: One major "flaw" I see in your implementation of fakeMap is that it doesn't perform a HasProperty check on each iteration which is required according to the spec. Meaning that if you have an Array with holes, Array.prototype.map will ignore these entries, while your fakeMap will just use undefined there.